# Is it possible to implement Webservices from Akka

Tags: akka, esb

I'm quiet new to Akka. Right now in the initial stages...
The reason why I insist on Akka is because I would like to leverage its distributed capabilities in my project 
The main implication will be servicing **REST based Web services** on top of Akka if possible .. 
if so ...  is it possible to invoke RESTful call to Akka and fork various services on the basis on a REST call
 
Can someone give me some insight about this ..

Comment: Have you ever heard of [spray](http://spray.io/)?

Comment: @agilesteel : Yes I have heard of it .... but i'm new to Scala so i couldn't get much hand-on on it .. can Spray be used with Akka for what I have metioned ... From different forums I even got options like Play2.0 and Apache Camel but not sure where to head ...

Comment: Spray will serve HTTP on top of Akka, but if you are planning to use Java, then check out Play mini. Here is a [blog post](http://letitcrash.com/post/17888436664/a-sample-application-showcasing-play-mini-and-akka) showcasing it (also in Scala, but possible from Java).

Comment: @agilesteel : Thanks for the reply .. i would like to know specifically if registering and serving a webService and  forking of multiple services is possible by integrating Akka with spray or play as in the similar fashion done by various ESB's ...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Spray](http://spray.io), which offers `spray-can`, a REST web server on top of Akka:

> The spray-routing module provides a high-level, very flexible routing
>   DSL for elegantly defining RESTful web services. Normally you would
>   use it either on top of a spray-can HttpServer or inside of a servlet
>   container together with spray-servlet.

You can register your services with Spray under the URLs you want them to be served, including authentication and authorisation. Take a look at the [example projects](http://spray.io/documentation/spray-routing/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

https://bitbucket.org/kraythensoft/ecplat

Check out that project. I am doing exactly what you are asking, adding in functionality release by release to form something of a howto for Spray, Akka, Squeryl all on Scala.